# Assessment year for ITNS 280 Challan

Tags: income-tax, india

For filing self assessment tax under ITNS challan 280 during current financial year 2015-2016 what will be the assessment year 2015-16 or 2016-17 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assessment year is always ahead of the financial year. So for financial year 2015-2016, the assessment year is 2016-2017.